# Ввод в Java подобно C++

Tags: java, c++

В C++ имеет место конструкция

```
while (cin >> i >> j) {
    // Что-то
}
```

Как организовать аналогичное в Java?

Comment: Видимо, вам нужен [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: А что предпочтительней использовать Scanner или BufferedReader?

Comment: Reader считывает ввод в символьный буфер.
Scanner считывает ввод и распознает отдельные токены по заказу. Если вам это не нужно - используйте Reader. Ответы Vitaliy неплохо демонстрируют разницу.

Comment: Scanner гораздо медленней работает, если сравнивать с BufferedReader.

Comment: зато Сканнер проще в написании. В простых приложениях нет особого смысла гнаться за производительностью. Разница неощутима.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       char[] buff = new char[255];
       try {
           while (bReader.read(buff) != -1){              
               // Что-то
           }
       } finally {
           bReader.close();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       String s = scanner.next();
       while (s != null){         // никогда null не будет, проверку свою вставить
           // Что-то
           s = scanner.next();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: а еще лучше так:  

    String line = null;
    while (null != (line = s.nextLine()) )
    {
      // делаем что-то нужное
    }